# Typo3 10.4.9 / Exbase: DataMapper delievers object array with empty/null properties by using a own class extends tt_address

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x

I'm using the datamapper in my extension to get a object array of my querybuilder result. It worked under Typo3 8.7, but not anymore under Typo3 10.4.9. The querybuilder delivers the correct result. After the datamapper took my results from the querybuilder, the object array has the correct number of entries and the properties; but the properties are empty/null.

```
...
/**
 * Datamaper
 *
 * @var DataMapper
 * @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\Inject
 */
protected DataMapper $datamapper;

...

$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tt_address');

$records = $queryBuilder
    ->select('tt_address.*')
    ->from('tt_address')
    ->leftJoin(
        'tt_address',
        'tt_content',
        'content',
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('content.tx_myext_parent', $queryBuilder->quoteIdentifier('tt_address.uid'))
    )
    ->where(
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('tt_address.deleted', 0),
        $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('tt_address.hidden', 0)
    )
    ->groupBy('tt_address.uid')
    ->execute()->fetchAll();

$result = $this->datamapper->map(\Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Adresse::class, $records);
```

My class:

```
class Adresse extends \FriendsOfTYPO3\TtAddress\Domain\Model\Address
{
...
/**
 * teaser
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected string $teaser = '';
...
```

Do you have any idea what's missing or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The properties of your model might need a setter or be public.

Comment: setters and getters are all public. I didn't get the property values of the extended class tt_address as well and they are public for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the mapping has changed since Typo3 10.0.
The solution can be found here:

[Typo3 docs](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Breaking-87623-ReplaceConfigpersistenceclassesTyposcriptConfiguration.html)